# Complex Date Conditional Formatting for when a status is marked DONE

Tags: date, google-sheets, conditional-formatting

I used to have a numbers spreadsheet that would change to pink if a deadline was the next day and bold red if the deadline was today or after today.  That is easy.  But then if I had marked the status column as "DONE," the red would disappear, indicatiing it's no longer urgent because, obviously, it's done.  I can't figure this out in Google Sheets.  And it doesn't seem to be working in numbers anymore either, so I can't work from there.

See photo for conditional formatting rules I have already set.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

Conditional Formatting in F3:F

Select Custom Formula.

Input formula:  `=D3="Done"`

Then drag this rule above the other rules.  This rule will then take precedence.

[image: Screenshot1]

[image: Screenshot2]

If I misunderstood your question or you are not getting the desired results, let me know.

Comment: @Lauren Lawrence, did this work for you?